# How do i wire this 2 switches light switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, troubleshooting

This light switch was failing for a while and I removed it from the wall so I could see what the problem was. After inspecting it, I realized that it was a bad connection on the wires in the light switch. My problem is that the wall only has 3 wires.

Now let me explain how it was behaving before: the left switch would turn the ceiling lights, and the right switch would turn on a couple of lights that I have on the mirror. What I don't understand is how that could be accomplished with only 3 wires.

In the wall I have 2 black and 1 red wire. Each black wire, when paired with the red wire, turns on one of the lights respectively, as it should.

How would I wire this in such a way that I would have the same behavior? And why does it have 2 holes per switch?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/bYXnDXD.jpeg]

[image]

Comment: The red is your hot and the two blacks are your load for each set of lights. The neutrals are tied together probably up by the lights. Do you have a diagram of the switch?  Can't you wire it up like it was before?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the box in the wall?

Comment: @JACK i do not have a diagram of the switch unfortunately and i wasn't the one who installed it so i do not know how it was.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just updated the original post with the box wiring, but theres nothing else other than those 3 wires.

Comment: @PedroCosta -- can you post a shot looking squarely into the back of the box please?

Comment: ProTip™: this is why you take a picture of the wiring _before_ you take the old thing apart! Consider this lesson learned. ;)